# Concatenate values

Tags: sql, concatenation

I want to concatenate all pair options in my column.

I have an table:

```
ID    num
1     10
2     20
3     30
```

and I want to create a query that will give me the following result:

```
10,20    
10,30   
20,10   
20,30   
30,10   
30,20
```

Also i want second query that will return without multiples(10,20=20,10)

```
10,20
10,30   
20,30
```

How can I get the 2 above in 2 different queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one I would do a cartesian product filtering the equal ones.

```
SELECT a.num, b.num
FROM tablename a, tablename b
WHERE a.num != b.num // Unless you want to exclude by ID
```

For the second, I would force one side to be bigger than the other.

```
SELECT a.num, b.num
FROM tablename a, tablename b
WHERE a.num < b.num
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table name is **"mytable"**.
1st Query:

```
Select 
t1.num,
t2.num
from mytable t1 join mytable t2 on
t1.ID!=t2.ID
```

2nd Query:

```
Select 
t1.num,
t2.num
from mytable t1 join mytable t2 on
t1.ID<t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use self join to get desired results. Use || to concatenate the columns. If the table name is t
Query for the first will be:

```
select t1.num||','|| t2.num
from t t1 join t t2
on t1.id!=t2.id
```

The second result can be obtained using below query:

```
Select 
t1.num||','|| t2.num
from t t1 join t t2 on
t1.id<t2.id
```